# Styled Components does not style the container

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using react app and using the styled-components package for styling. My task is to move the container to the center of the page using styled.div, but it cant work. Anyone can help? Thanks for advance:)

//below is the html

```
<FormContainer>
    <div className="form-container">
      <form>
          <h1>Sign In</h1>
              <div className="input-container">
               <input type="email" required></input>
              </div>
       </form>
     </div>
 </FormContainer>
```

//below is my styled-components

```
const FormContainer = styled.div`
display: grid;
jusitify-content: center;
position: relative;
z-index:5;

.form-container{
position: relative;
width:28.125rem;
height:41.25 rem;
padding:4 rem;
}`;
```

Comment: Can you try using `& > .form-container` instead of `.form-container` in your CSS? That might solve the issue

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not work